# Numpy confusion with boolean indexing and broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array y:

```
y = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)
```

5 rows, 7 columns.  Now I create a boolean 1-d 5-element mask which picks out the rows I want (following the doc at [numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)):

```
b = np.array([False, False, True, False, True])
```

Then `y[b]` returns the rows of interest.  But the doc is confusing: it says

> Boolean arrays must be of the same shape as the array being indexed, or broadcastable to the same shape.

And b is *not* broadcastable with y:

```
>>> np.broadcast_arrays(y, b)
ValueError: shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 1.
```

because broadcasting works by matching the trailing dimensions and working backwards.

In this case of boolean indexing, there's clearly some different rule at work; is the doc wrong or am I just misunderstanding it?  If I did what the doc suggests and make b be of shape (5,1) it doesn't pick out the rows; it just gets the first column of each selected row and returns that as a 1-d array.

I suspect the real rule is that the boolean object's dims must match the original array's *initial* dims, and it selects the values of each of those dims where the boolean is true, returning all elements of any trailing dims.  But I can't find anything official that says that's how it works.

So my question is, (a) am I doing it right and the doc is just wrong?  (b) am I reading the wrong doc?  (c) is there a better/different way to do it or to understand it?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me... But we'd have to ask the devs whether this is a bug in numpy or in the numpy docs :)

Comment: I'd say if it's a bug it's a bug in the docs. `y[b]` is equivalent to `y[b, :]`, and makes sense as such.  If `c` is boolean with `shape` `(7,)`, then `y[c]` is `y[c,:]` and so doesn't work, because it's not broadcasting, it's slicing.  You must use `y[:, c]`.

Comment: It is a documentation issue. Boolean indexing has nothing to do with broadcasting. Please correct the documentation if you feel it, you can easily do it on github.

Comment: @seberg: I'm happy to help.  Should I use the wiki doc editor at  http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy.doc.indexing/?  Or just check out the source (I assume the doc is in there somewhere) and make a pull request?

Comment: @GaryO, I think in principle the wikidoc might work, but it is probably easier to create a pull request. If it is just small text changes, you can even do it via the github "edit" button. EDIT: though then doing fixups is probably hard, so probably better to do a real checkout unless it is just a typo fix.

Comment: @seberg: pull request created.  Thanks for the push!

Comment: Indexing with a boolean like `b=np.array([True,False,True])` is like indexing with an integer array `np.array([0,2])`.  `b` doesn't have to have the same length of the axis is operating on.

Comment: the numpy `reference` is clearer than the `user guide`.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj.  I'll update my doc fix to note that.  I agree the ref is better, but the user guide should at least be correct. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reduction of `y[b]` appears to do what you want.  I don't think it's out of step with the docs and there is not a special case for boolean vs numbers for broadcasting here.

```
y[b] # gives what you want
# broadcast booleans
np.broadcast_arrays(b, y) #gives the error you saw
np.broadcast_arrays(b[:,np.newaxis], y) #broadcasts.
# same as broadcast numbers
np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(5), y) #ALSO gives the error you saw
np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(5)[:,np.newaxis], y) #broadcasts.
```

Comment: The numpy reference says `y[b]` is effectively the same as `y[b.nonzero()]`.